# On error, force function to return

Tags: vba

I have a function that returns a string
on error, I would like it to return a specific value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `On Error GoTo` to branch to a specific label if an error occurs:

```
Function YourFunction() {
  On Error GoTo ErrorLabel
  ... your code ...
  Exit Function
  ErrorLabel:
    YourFunction = yourspecificvalue
}
```